# How to insert 11k columns data to a hive table, in parquet format?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I am running a spark job in which I am trying to insert 11k columns data into a table, after selecting from a dataset **ds**, in parquet format.

```
ds.repartition(123).write().mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy").insertInto("db.iParquetTable");
```

The data size is 1232 MB. Using below configuration to launch spark job.

```
spark-submit -v \
--driver-memory 3g \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 3 \
--executor-cores 2 \
--executor-memory 2g
--class com.package.Driver \
/user/home/mohit/testRun.jar
```

But the job gets stuck while inserting the data into parquetTable, and no executors could be seen running on YARN's executors UI. Not sure what all performance issues I am facing here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is 'ds' supposed to be a DataSet? Then what is repartition("...")? Repartition can only get columns and/or num-of-partitions.

Comment: @NirHedvat .. `repartition()` , is repartitioning the data. Here it will create 123 repartitions of 10 MB each

Comment: I know what it means. You've just edited your question from "123" to 123 (string to int)

Comment: Yes I did that, mistakenly typed it. Can you please help with it?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: There is a table1 which is comprising of 11k columns. From table1, I am selecting all 11k transformed columns into a dataset **ds** , and using this dataset to insert into table2 using above code. The jobs is getting stuck at insertInto() function. Not sure what sort of performance issue is this.